# Please explain this mongodb query and its result

Tags: mongodb

The query goes as follows

```
db.restaurants.find({$and : [{"grades.score" : {$gt:80}},{"grades.score" : {$lt:100}}]})
```

it was written with the idea in mind of retrieving restaurants with a score of 80 to 100

why does this query return the following document in its result. the below document does not have any grade element in the grades sub-document which falls in the range of "greater than 80 AND less than 100".

i have tried using this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("572eb5df1d739cc73c21fab1"),
    "address" : {
            "building" : "65",
            "coord" : [
                    -73.9782725,
                    40.7624022
            ],
            "street" : "West   54 Street",
            "zipcode" : "10019"
    },
    "borough" : "Manhattan",
    "cuisine" : "American ",
    "grades" : [
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-08-22T00:00:00Z"),
                    "grade" : "A",
                    "score" : 11
            },
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-03-28T00:00:00Z"),
                    "grade" : "C",
                    "score" : 131
            },
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2013-09-25T00:00:00Z"),
                    "grade" : "A",
                    "score" : 11
            },
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2013-04-08T00:00:00Z"),
                    "grade" : "B",
                    "score" : 25
            },
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2012-10-15T00:00:00Z"),
                    "grade" : "A",
                    "score" : 11
            },
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2011-10-19T00:00:00Z"),
                    "grade" : "A",
                    "score" : 13
            }
    ],
    "name" : "Murals On 54/Randolphs'S",
    "restaurant_id" : "40372466"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because both conditions are true. When you don't specify indices for `grades.score` it search through all elements of the array. And it **does** find an item with `score > 80` (which is 131). At the same time there exist other items that are less then 100.

In human language you request "a document that contains score greater then 80 and at the same time contains score less then 100". You don't specify that it should be the same score that satisfy these conditions.

What you're looking for I guess is a query for simultaneously checking range for each element.

```
{ "grades" : { $elemMatch: { score: { $gt:80, $lt:100 } } } }
```

Comment: so there is no way to do this with a simple $and? because i thought it should return documents which satisfied both of the $and

Comment: as I've already mentioned you deal with an array. So you should instruct Mongo to iterate through all elements of array and check if any of the items satisfy the condition. This is done by operator `$elemMatch`. I've edited my answer with an explanation. Hope it helps

Comment: oh, i thought if i used a $and it would combine to 2 conditions into 1. but instead it checks for the validity of both. using elemMatch gets the right answer. can you give a quick answer. Can this be accomplished any way using "grades.score"?

Comment: `grade.score` is not a value. Mongo expands it for you and iterates `grades` array. What's your limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah as said by @Kirill Slatin, your both conditions are true in that case. So, for your required result, check out the following solution with an explanation for your better understanding:

Using $lte and $gte separately,

```
db.products.find({score:{$gt:'80'}})

db.products.find({score:{$lt:'100'}})
```

First statement will return the result with score of 80 and gretaer than 80  and Second statement will return the score results with 100 and less than 100

Using $lt and $gt together

```
db.products.find({score:{$gt:80,$lt:100}})
```

The above Query will return the score results greater than 80 and less than 100

Comment: where you're using the gt and lt together. shouldnt it return only the documents where the score value is between 80 and 100?

Comment: yes, of course.. that was an example, you can modify the values as per your requirement.

Comment: but it doesnt. this db.restaurants.find({"grades.score":{$gt:80,$lt:100}}) gives me 1 document (mentioned in the question )where none of the scores are between 80&100.

Comment: and what was the result score that u got

Comment: i have pasted it in the question. look at the scores